# Jetpack Compose saving state on orientation change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Android Jetpack's Compose and have been trying to figure out how to save state for orientation changes.

My train of thought was making a class a ViewModel. As that generally worked when I would work with Android's traditional API.

I have used remember {} and mutableState {} to update the UI when information has been changed.
Please validate if my understanding is correct...

remember = Saves the variable and allows access via .value, this allows values to be cache. But its main use is to not reassign the variable on changes.

mutableState = Updates the variable when something is changed.

Many blog posts say to use @Model, however, the import gives errors when trying that method.
So, I added a : ViewModel()

However, I believe my remember {} is preventing this from working as intended?

Can I get a point in the right direction?

```
@Composable
fun DefaultFlashCard() {

    val flashCards = remember { mutableStateOf(FlashCards())}
    

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))

    MaterialTheme {


        val typography = MaterialTheme.typography
        var question = remember { mutableStateOf(flashCards.value.currentFlashCards.question) }



        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(30.dp).then(Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
                .then(Modifier.wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center))
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(350.dp)
                    .border(width = 4.dp,
                            color = Gray,
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                    .clickable(
                            onClick = {
                                question.value = flashCards.value.currentFlashCards.answer })
                    .gravity(align = Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(2.dp),
                    backgroundColor = DarkGray,
                    gravity = Alignment.Center) {
                Text("${question.value}",
                        style = typography.h4, textAlign = TextAlign.Center, color = White
                )
            }
        }

        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                horizontalGravity = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {

            Text("Flash Card application",
                    style = typography.h6,
                    color = Black)

            Text("The following is a demonstration of using " +
                    "Android Compose to create a Flash Card",
                    style = typography.body2,
                    color = Black,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center)

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
            Button(onClick = {
                flashCards.value.incrementQuestion();
                question.value = flashCards.value.currentFlashCards.question },
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                    content = { Text("Next Card") },
                    backgroundColor = Cyan)
        }
    }
}


data class Question(val question: String, val answer: String) {
}


class FlashCards: ViewModel() {

    var flashCards = mutableStateOf( listOf(
            Question("How many Bananas should go in a Smoothie?", "3 Bananas"),
            Question("How many Eggs does it take to make an Omellete?", "8 Eggs"),
            Question("How do you say Hello in Japenese?", "Konichiwa"),
            Question("What is Korea's currency?", "Won")
    ))

    var currentQuestion = 0

    val currentFlashCards
        get() = flashCards.value[currentQuestion]

    fun incrementQuestion() {
        if (currentQuestion + 1 >= flashCards.value.size) currentQuestion = 0 else currentQuestion++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

There is another approach to handle config changes in Compose, it is `rememberSaveable`. As [docs says](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#introducing-state):

> While `remember` helps you retain state across recompositions, the state is not retained across configuration changes. For this, you must use `rememberSaveable`. `rememberSaveable` automatically saves any value that can be saved in a Bundle. For other values, you can pass in a custom saver object.

It seems that [Mohammad's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63746043/12788133) is more robust, but this one seems simpler.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the Bundle imposes 2 restrictions: the Object to store must be Serializable and it can't be large otherwise we get a TransactionTooLarge exception. I would like to store an object in memory during the lifecycle of the Composable (shorter than the lifecycle of the ViewModel) that survives config change.

Comment: Remember to add configChanges tag for your activity in manifest too, for rememberSaveable to work.
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"

Answer (score 15):

### Updated answer

There are 2 built-in ways for persisting state in Compose:

1. `remember`: exists to save state in Composable functions between ***recompositions***.
2. `rememberSaveable`: `remember` **only** save state across *recompositions* and **doesn't** handle *configuration changes* and *process death*, so to survive  configuration changes and process death you should use `rememberSaveable` instead.

But there are some problems with `rememberSaveable` too:

1. It supports primitive types out of the box, but for more complex data, like `data class`, you must create a `Saver` to explain how to persist state into bundle,
2. `rememberSaveable` uses `Bundle` under the hood, so there is a limit of how much data you can persist in it, if data is too large you will face `TransactionTooLarge` exception.

with above said, below solutions are available:

1. setting `android:configChanges`in `Manifest` to avoid activity recreation in configuration changes. (**not useful in process death, also doesn't save you from being recreated in Wallpaper changes in Android 12**)
2. Using a combination of `ViewModel` + `remeberSaveable` + data persistence in storage

=======================================================

### Old answer

Same as before, you can use Architecture Component ViewModel to survive configuration changes.

You should initialize your ViewModel in Activity/Fragment and then pass it to Composable functions.

```
class UserDetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: UserDetailViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return ComposeView(context = requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                AppTheme {
                    UserDetailScreen(
                        viewModel = viewModel
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your ViewModel should expose the ViewState by something like LiveData or Flow

UserDetailViewModel:

```
class UserDetailViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _userData = MutableLiveData<UserDetailViewState>()
    val userData: LiveData<UserDetailViewState> = _userData


    // or

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<UserDetailViewState>()
    val state: StateFlow<UserDetailViewState>
        get() = _state

}
```

Now you can observe this state in your composable function:

```
@Composable
fun UserDetailScreen(
    viewModel:UserDetailViewModel
) {
    val state by viewModel.userData.observeAsState()
    // or
    val viewState by viewModel.state.collectAsState()

}
```

Comment: This is definitely the preferred approach to persisting state in a way that survives configuration change. Please mark as correct if you can! : x

Comment: The problem of this approach is that the ViewModel lives at the Activity/Fragment level and `remember` is local to a Composable. If we have Composable UI elements that come and go inside the same Activity I would like to have state that is read and disposed together with the lifecycle of the Composable not with the longer lifecycle of the Activity. Plus surviving config changes

Comment: Remember to add configChanges tag for your activity in manifest too, for rememberSaveable to work.
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"