# The LazyColumn is always reload twice, it has duplicate content twice

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

This is my code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun GetPathList(context: Activity, path: String) {
    val resultJson = remember { mutableStateListOf<RequestData.PathData>() }
    var loadingPicController by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    if (loadingPicController) {
        Text("loading")
    }
    thread {
        resultJson.addAll(RequestData().getPath(path))
        loadingPicController = false // Loading End
    }
    LazyColumn(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)) {
        items(resultJson) { item ->
            Surface(modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                val intent = Intent(context, PathDetailsActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("folderName", item.name)
                intent.putExtra("path", "$path/${item.name}")
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = 24.dp, top = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {

                    Icon(painter = Icons.Document, contentDescription = "Files", modifier = Modifier.size(28.dp))
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp)) {
                        Text(item.name, fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium, fontSize = 14.sp)
                        Text(item.type, fontWeight = FontWeight.Light, fontSize = 12.sp)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The right result is here
[image]
However, With the code , After the loading finshing, the list was reloaded twice.
it should only load once.
But now after the loading animation is over it is loaded twice and the content is repeated twice
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69629575/3585796) of the ways to correctly get initial data.

Answer (score 2):

Items come with a key parameter that you can use to prevent any duplicates and also to ensure that if there is an update the right item is updated. in any case if this fails you can use **list.distinct()** to help clear out any duplicates

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because every time your composable function is executed, a new `thread` is started and it's adding all the items again.
Basically the current flow is:

1. `GetPathList` is executed. The `loadingPicController` is `true` and a new thread is executed.
2. When the `thread` finishes, the `loadingPicController` flag is set to `false`, causing a recomposition (`GetPathList` is called again).
3. `GetPathList` is called again. The `thread` is triggered again, adding the items again. Since `loadingPicController` is `false` already, the recomposition didn't happen.